# Showing unique child DIV when clicking a TD - jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which is structured like a calendar, 1 table row with 31 table cells.

I am trying to **show** the **child div** of the TD clicked on so that its unique to that day.

At the moment if i click on the second TD it shows cell 1's div content, I need it to show its own child div content.

I have the popup working but I just need a hand figuring out how to show the unique day div content.

```js
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup unique to that cell 
function openPopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="openPopup()">
        <p class="day-number-red">1 </p>
        <p class="sports-on-day">
          Cricket <br> Tennis <br> Darts </p>

        <div class="popup">
          <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Example 1</span>
        </div>



      </td>


      <td onclick="openPopup()">
        <p class="day-number-red">2 </p>
        <p class="sports-on-day">- </p>

        <div class="popup">
          <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Example 2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Identifiers in HTML __must__ be __Unique__, You can't use `myPopup` id at multiple locations

Comment: instead of writing `openPopup()` to each `td`  `onclick` event, declare a  single function and bind it to the `td` of your table via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery access `<td>`

```js
// remove id of popup #1
$('table tbody tr td').on('click', function(e){
  // your code 
  //...
    var titles = $(this).find(".sports-on-day").html();
    var desc = $(this).find(".popup").html();
    
    var md = $('#td-detail');
    
    $('.modal-title').html(titles);
    $('.modal-body').html(desc);
    md.modal('show');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>title 1</th>
    <th>title 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="day-number-red">1 </p>
        <p class="sports-on-day">
          Cricket <br> Tennis <br> Darts
        </p>
        <div class="popup">
          <span class="popuptext">Example 1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="day-number-red">2 </p>
        <p class="sports-on-day">- </p>
        <div class="popup">
          <span class="popuptext">Example 2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>


<!-- Modal [bootstrap] -->
<div class="modal fade" id="td-detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="td-title-md" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="td-title-md"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working best by showing me the contents of the TD which is good, however I am not sure what code I need to show my popup DIV, any idea?

Comment: Added the following to 'Your Code' section' to get it working: 
     $(this).find(".popuptext").css("visibility","visible");

Comment: In jquery can use `:visible` to call visible selector ref : https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the element itself in the onclick function

```
<td onclick="openPopup(this)"> 
// ...
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup unique to that cell 
function openPopup(ele) {
    // get the div with ele
}
```

Or with jquery:

```
$('.yourTable').on("click", "td", function(ele){
    // show your div with ele
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a same `function` multiple times(depending on the days) to your `html` bind the `function` to the element you want it to work on ,to avoid increasing the code on the `DOM`.

you can add this code to your javascript:

```
var td = document.querySelector('table td');
td.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var text = this.querySelector('.popuptext').innerHTML;//here you get the day
  //now do your code to display the date here

});
```

Comment: Hey Ive tried this but no luck
var td = document.querySelector('table td');

td.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var text = this.querySelector('.popuptext').innerHTML;//here you get the day
  
  //now do your code to display the date here
  text.classList.add("popup.show");
  
});

Comment: @StanHowe the object `this` inside the click function will represent the `td` , on which the `click event` has occurred & more about the `this` keyword can be found at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/2417602). And for the code `text.classList.add("popup.show");` will not work as the `text` is just a `string object`  and not an `DOM` hence will throw an error of `undefined` object. If you want to add classes to the object with class `.popup` do a query selector on it and then add the class like `var popup = this.querySelector('.popup'); popup.classList.add('show');`.